# How to set custom JAXBContext

Tags: java, jaxb, annotations, jax-ws, java-metro-framework

i would like to ask a question about *[@UsesJAXBContext](https://jax-ws.java.net/nonav/2.2.8/javadocs/rt/index.html?com/sun/xml/ws/developer/UsesJAXBContext.html)* annotation in jax-ws. I try to make it work on client side but I'm probably missing something. Here is my case:

I've got webservice with operation:

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "putToQueue")
public boolean put(@WebParam(name = "queueName") String queueName, @WebParam(name = "element") Object element) {
    return queues.get(queueName).offer(element);
}
```

On the client side i generated QueueService and Queue (port)... and other stuff... [respones requests. In this case irrelevant.]
I would like to let user define object that he/she could put to queue. However to invoke operation *put(...)* I need bind object (that I try to send) into JAXBContext. I could do that by 
*@XmlSeeAlso* in the top of the generated Queue stub [i tried this one and it works]. Nonetheless I need more generic solution that help me bind object at runtime. 
I thought that I could create *@QueueMessage* annotation and *ClientJAXBContextFactory* and add marked class to the context when creating it.

```
public class ClientJAXBContextFactory implements JAXBContextFactory {

    @Override
    public JAXBRIContext createJAXBContext(SEIModel seim, List<Class> classes, List<TypeReference> references) throws JAXBException {
        Reflections reflections = new Reflections("");
        Set<Class<?>> annotated = reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith(QueueMessage.class);
        classes.addAll(annotated);

        return JAXBContextFactory.DEFAULT.createJAXBContext(seim, classes, references);
    }
}
```

Next i tried use *@UsesJAXBContext* on top of generated Queue.

```
@WebService(name = "Queue")
@UsesJAXBContext(ClientJAXBContextFactory.class)
public interface Queue {
...
}
```

But *createJAXBContext(...)* is not invoked and jax-ws just simply create his JAXBContextImpl.

I have read:

http://weblogs.java.net/blog/jitu/archive/2008/08/control_of_jaxb.html

http://www.techques.com/question/1-5627173/Specify-JAXB-Packages-in-SLSB-and-JAX-WS

and some question on stackOverFlow. I would be grateful for advises.
Is it possible to implement idea presented in my question?

Also i might add that on the server side ... *@UsesJAXBContext* works. But its important for me to make it work on the client side.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok I could manage problem i was facing. Still i couldn't use *@UsesJAXBContext* with client consuming the webservice. But i found that this annotations are tied to beans with post-fix Feature. So there is a class *UsesJAXBContextFeature*

https://jax-ws.java.net/nonav/2.2.7/javadocs/com/sun/xml/ws/developer/UsesJAXBContextFeature.html

and it could be passed as argument of port or service(service since jax-ws 2.2). I have got a little trouble with versions so i decided to generate class and use jax-ws 2.1. Now i just simply create port like this:

```
new QueueService().getQueuePort(new UsesJAXBContextFeature(new ClientJAXBContextFactory()));
```

And it works!